# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log^a(n)/n^b$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I prove that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\ln(n))^a}{n^b} = 0 \;\forall a,b > 0 $$
? Intuitively it is clear to me because of the behavior of the functions. Thanks for all.

**Edit** I'm not able to use L'Hopital rule. Sorry.

Comment: I would try L'Hospital. At least it gives that it is enough to prove for $a\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Afer the appropriate change of variable ($x=\ln n$ and then $y=bx$), this boils down to
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{y^a}{e^y}=0.
$$

Let $n$ be an integer such that $n>a$.
Then, for $y\geq 0$,
$$
e^y=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{y^k}{k!}\geq \frac{y^n}{n!}.
$$
So
$$
0\leq \frac{y^a}{e^y}\leq \frac{n!y^a}{y^n}=\frac{n!}{y^{n-a}}.
$$

Conclude with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Ben Ward I guess you have seen the series definition of the exponential, and that you are allowed to use it, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for this method!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

$lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {log(n)}{n^a}=0$     $ a>0$
(This can be proved with L'hopital's)

Use this to prove your result.

Comment: Thanks, this solves everything but I forgot to clarify that I am not able to use L'Hopital's rule. Sorry.

Comment: It can be proved without L'Hopital's , or series definition of exponential.  Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{a^x}=0$ and we get the result. You can prove it by writing a as 1+p p>0 and then using the binomial theorem.