# How do I calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\ln x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

I was thinking about the reasons behind $0^0=1$ and I remember one of my friends studying math arguing about the continuity of the function $x^x$ in $0$. But when I write as $$x^x=e^{x\ln x}$$ I am now looking at $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\ln x$$
Graphically I can see in Mathematica that it goes to $0.$ But I can't calculate by using a Taylor expansion, because I can't expand log around $0$. How do you prove that?

Comment: Usually people would do that with L'Hospital, byt writing $\ln x/ (1/x)$.

Comment: You want to take the limit from the right...

Comment: You can put $n=1/x$ in this other new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303933/

Comment: A wrong answer : $x\ln x=x+\int_0^x \ln u\,du$ so has limit $0$ when $x\to 0$. :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitute $x = e^y$, then if $x \to 0$, $y\to -\infty$. So the limit becomes $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \ln x = \lim\limits_{y\to -\infty} y\cdot e^{y}  = 0, $$ because $e^\cdot$ is stronger than any polynomial.

Answer (score 7):

L'Hopital's rule can be used,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Using L'Hopital's Rule (as it has$\frac{-\infty}{\infty } $ form, and $\ln(x)$ and $1/x$ are differentiable to the right of $0$) we have,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{d\ln x}{dx}}{\frac{d\frac{1}{x}}{dx}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(-x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$ln(x) =  -\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^k (x-1)^k \over k}$  for $|x-1|<1$

Then $xln(x) =  -\sum_{k=1}^\infty {x(-1)^k (x-1)^k \over k}$ wich converges for $x=0$.

q.e.d.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $y = 1/x$,
$x^x
=(1/y)^{1/y}
=\dfrac1{y^{1/y}}
$.

So,
if we can show that
$\lim_{y \to \infty} y^{1/y}
= 1$,
then $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x = 1$.

Here (again)
is a simple proof that
$n^{1/n} \to 1$
as $n \to \infty$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+n^{-1/2})^n
\gt 1+n^{-1/2}n
=1+n^{1/2}
> n^{1/2}$.

Raising to the
$2/n$ power,
$(1+n^{-1/2})^2
> n^{1/n}$
so that
$n^{1/n}
< (1+n^{-1/2})^2
= 1+2n^{-1/2} + n^{-1}
< 1+3n^{-1/2}
$.

Since
$n^{1/n} > 1$,
$n^{1/n} \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x\ln x)'=\ln x+1\to -\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$ we conclude that $(x\ln x)$ is a decreasing function near $0$.

Since $x\ln(x)\le 0$ then for $x$ sufficiently small we have $|x\ln x|<C$ for some constant $C$.

Let's have $x\to 0^+$, $y\to 0^+$ so that $u=xy\to 0^+$.

$|u\ln u|=|xy\ln(xy)|=|xy(\ln x+\ln y)|=|y(x\ln x)+x(y\ln y)|\le|y(x\ln x)|+|x(y\ln y)|\le C(|x|+|y|)\to 0$